# How it can modify formset's forms in an iteration

Tags: python, django

As far as I know if you iterate over a list and update its element, you dont update list itself.

```
list_var = ['a','b','c']
for l in list_var:
    l = 'x'
print list_var
```

it prints out ['a', 'b', 'c'], not X's

Below code belongs to one of my project.

```
    if hasattr(self.model, 'get_disabled_always_fields'):
        for field in self.model.get_disabled_always_fields():
            for form in self.formset_instance:
                try:
                    form.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True
                except KeyError as e:
                    pass
```

It updates the list element and it effect the list we were iterating.

Question is , why formset forms affected by for loop modifications.

Comment: When you do `a[b]=c`, you are actually modifying the original list itself because that is essentially `a.__setitem__(b, c)`

Comment: But I do form.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True, not self.formset_instance[1].fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly'] = True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How variable references work

`a = 1` really just means "make `a` an alias for the value carried by the expression `1`". `a = 1 + 2` really just means "evaluate `1 + 2` and then make `a` and alias for the result of that.

However, `a[0] = 1` means "set the first value of `a` to the expression `1`".

So, if you're looping through a list, you're essentially going through each value in the iterable and for each value, you set `form` to that value. Doing `form = a` within the list just changes the meaning of `form`. Doing `form[0] = a` modifies `form`.

If you don't want it to be modified, consider cloning form at the beginning of the loop using `form = form[:]`.

I hope the concepts of how variables work in this case is now clear; it can be a bit confusing!

Answer (score 0):

In first example you assign elements of `list_var` to `l`, then reassigning the same exact `l` variable.

In second example you operate with `form.fields[field].widget.attrs['readonly']` and not `field`(by which you iterate). So if you would be doing:

```
for field in self.model.get_disabled_always_fields():
    for form in self.formset_instance:
        field = 'something'  # or
        form = 'something2'
```

nothing would change as it haven't in first example.